# Basic use of `this` in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm fairly adept in Javascript but I'm having a hard time understanding how Ember is handling the `this` context in certain scenarios.

I have a component controller:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  keyPress(e) {
    // here I want to call a method in the `actions` hash
    this.get('onAccept')
  },

  actions: {
    onAccept() {
      console.log('action accepted!')
    }
  }
}
```

Every time I run this though, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.get(...) is not a function
```

This seems to always happen when I have a method outside of the `actions` hash that needs to access a function inside the `actions` hash, **or** the other way around.

And this behavior seems necessary, because component events belong [outside of the actions hash](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/handling-events/).

**So how am I supposed to have event methods outside of the `actions` hash but still be able to call methods that belong inside of the `actions` hash?**

This seems to be a poorly documented part of controllers in Ember. Maybe I am just missing something here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: this.send(‘someActionName’) will let you call an action from another function

Comment: @handlebears Am I correct in assuming that all methods inside the `actions` of hash, basically should be considered part of the `route.js` file? Since we have to use `this.send()` when going from a controller method to a route method?

Comment: If you have the luxury of doing so, you may be interested in trying ember's native ES classes with ember-decorators. No need to use send or get. :)

Comment: @qarthandso note that send and sendAction are different. Send is useful when working in the same file, sendAction is for passing the action up the chain (and there are better ways to do that now). I put actions in the controller and pass them to components, or declare them directly in the components themselves that need them. You can’t pass actions straight from the route.js to the components. Just a weird quirk of routes.

Comment: To be clear, I have lots of actions that aren’t in routes/controllers. I put every action in components except things that save to the server, but that’s just personal preference.

Comment: Thank you @NullVoxPopuli and @handlebears. Would you please help me understand the section labeled "Actions" in [this article](https://medium.com/build-addepar/es-classes-in-ember-js-63e948e9d78e). (Search for the text "The actions hash on" to go right to it...) It says that the `actions` is typically merged with the `actions` hash of the superclass? Could someone elaborate on that? Where is this documented?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Maybe comment on the article to ask. I know that author is very active

Comment: Heya, author of the article in question here. You can find documentation on merged properties in the Ember API docs [here](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.3/classes/EmberObject/properties/mergedProperties?anchor=mergedProperties), and more specifically the API docs for Component show that actions inherits the parent class's actions [here](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.3/classes/Component/properties/actions?anchor=actions). This is a rarely used feature outside of predefined properties such as `actions` and `classNames`, which exist mostly because of historical reasons.

Comment: @pzuraq your comment is greatly appreciated. I'm understanding step by step. I quite like Ember the more I get into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call an action from outside the `actions` hash, use `this.send`

```
this.send('onAccept');
```

More information on `send` and `sendAction` can be found here: https://medium.com/ember-titbits/ember-send-and-sendaction-5e6ac9c80841